# Pass a Var to Constant Parameter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, type-conversion, constants, var

When I write this Code,

```dart
        TextFormField(
              cursorRadius: Radius.circular(26),
              cursorColor: Colors.green,
              onChanged: onTextInChange,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: texts.toForm[0],
                hintText: texts.toForm[1],
                helperText: texts.toForm[2],
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            )
```

And my *Texts* Class is look like this,

```
class Texts{
   let toForm = ['Enter Your Name', 'John Fernando', 'This is a Helper Text'];
}
```

I got an error called,

```
Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
```

These  *helperText*, *hintText*, *helperText* are expecting constant Strings, but I want to pass them through a class like this using a List, not to Directly Specify the Value.

So, what should I do?

Please help me! I'm new to Flutter and Dart!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `const` from parent i.e `InputDecoration`

```
        TextFormField(
          cursorRadius: Radius.circular(26),
          cursorColor: Colors.green,
          onChanged: onTextInChange,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: texts.toForm[0],
            hintText: texts.toForm[1],
            helperText: texts.toForm[2],
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: It worked!, Oh how a fool was I am XD, Thank you very much for your help!!, I really appreciate it...